# What causes the JVM to do a major garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I have a Java app which shows different GC behaviors in different environments. In one environment, the heap usage graph is a slow sawtooth with major GCs every 10 hours or so, only when the heap is >90% full. In another environment, the JVM does major GCs every hour on the dot (the heap is normally between 10% and 30% at these times).

My question is, what are the factors which cause the JVM to decide to do a major GC?

Obviously it collects when the heap is nearly full, but there is some other cause at play which I am guessing is related to an hourly scheduled task within my app (although there is no spike in memory usage at this time).

I assume GC behaviour depends heavily on the JVM; I am using:

- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_21 Oracle Corporation
- No specific GC options, so using the default settings for 64-bit server (PS MarkSweep and PS Scavenge)

Other info:

- This is a web app running in Tomcat 6.
- Perm gen hovers around 10% in both environments.
- The environment with the sawtooth behaviour has 7Gb max heap, the other has 14Gb.

Please, no guesswork. The JVM must have rules for deciding when to perform a major GC, and these rules must be encoded deep in the source somewhere. If anyone knows what they are, or where they are documented, please share!

Comment: *"In one environment... In another environment..."* What are the environments? What's different about them?

Comment: AFAIK the GC can be coerced into performing a garbage collection via hints, and i say coerced because I don't think you can implicitly force GC to perform a garbage collection.

Comment: @CeilingGecko You are correct, per specs you cannot force GC.  You can, however, ask nicely and maybe the JVM will comply.  In general, the JVM will do full GCs whenever it tries to instantiate an object in the heap and doesn't have the room to do so.  At least, that is my understanding.  There are other triggers for full GC, and a Google search for "what triggers a full GC" can find loads of info.  I believe the specifics around when the JVM determines it doesn't have room to instantiate an object are left up to the JVM developer.

Comment: Hmm, not sure but does a full old gen heap not trigger a full gc? If you are monitoring the entire heap it might seem largely empty but the old gen might be full?

Comment: @chris do you have -Xmx -r -Xms settings?

Comment: On a different JVM I once worked on, GC cycles were triggered by the amount of heap allocated -- after so many MB of heap allocation you'd get a GC.  I would imagine that something similar could be at work here.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what exactly do you want to know? It's Hotspot JVM running on 64-bit Linux. The cmd line args for the two JVMs are identical and pretty much standard, except one has -Xms14g -Xmx14g and the other has -Xms7g -Xmx7g.

Comment: @chris: I think I was fairly clear. It's standard debugging: If A does one thing, and B does something else, look at what's different between A and B. For instance, those command line arguments related to memory are different. Perhaps the servers have different amounts of memory. Or are different versions of Linux (even if just dot revs of the kernel). Or have different other processes running. Or...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Garbage collection is a [pretty complicated topic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1420082795), and while you could learn all the details about this, I think what’s happening in your case is pretty simple.

Sun’s [Garbage Collection Tuning guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html), under the “Explicit Garbage Collection” heading, warns:

> applications can interact with garbage collection … by invoking full garbage collections explicitly … This can force a major collection to be done when it may not be necessary … **One of the most commonly encountered uses of explicit garbage collection occurs with RMI … RMI forces full collections periodically**

That guide says that the default time between garbage collections is one minute, but the [sun.rmi Properties reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html), under `sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval` says:

> The default value is 3600000 milliseconds (one hour).

If you’re seeing major collections every hour in one application but not another, it’s probably because the application is using RMI, possibly only internally, and you haven’t added `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` to the startup flags.

Disable explicit GC, or test this hypothesis by setting `-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=7200000` and observing if GCs happen every two hours instead.

Comment: The tutorial is incorrect on this point. Nothing written in Java can 'force full collections periodically'. RMI calls System.gc(). It isn't the same thing. System.gc() is only a hint to the GC.

Comment: +1 I agree that this is the most likely cause. I'll check it out next week.

Answer (score 7):

I have found four conditions that can cause a major GC (given my JVM config):

1. The old gen area is full (even if it can be grown, a major GC will still be run first)
2. The perm gen area is full (even if it can be grown, a major GC will still be run first)
3. Someone is manually calling `System.gc()`: a bad library or something related to RMI (see links [1](http://alexandru-ersenie.com/2011/01/11/j2ee-full-garbage-collections-when-running-with-cms-garbage-collection-strategy/), [2](http://fedora.fiz-karlsruhe.de/docs/Wiki.jsp?page=Java+Heap+%26+GC+Tuning) and [3](https://www.java.net/node/690169))
4. The young gen areas are all full and nothing is ready to be moved into old gen (see [1](http://alexandru-ersenie.com/2011/01/11/j2ee-full-garbage-collections-when-running-with-cms-garbage-collection-strategy/))

As others have commented, cases 1 and 2 can be improved by allocating plenty of heap and permgen, and setting `-Xms` and `-Xmx` to the same value (along with the perm equivalents) to avoid dynamic heap resizing.

Case 3 can be avoided using the `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` flag.

Case 4 requires more involved tuning, e.g., `-XX:NewRatio=N` (see [Oracle's tuning guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html)).

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your configurations, since HotSpot  configures itself differently in different Java environments. For example, in a server with more than 2GB and two processors some JVMs will be configured in '-server' mode instead of the default '-client' mode, which configure the sizes of the memory spaces (generations) differently, and that has an impact as to when garbage collection will occur.

A full GC can occur automatically, but also if you call the garbage collector in your code (ex: using `System.gc()`). Automatically, it depends on how the minor collections are behaving.

There are at least two algorithms being used. If you are using defaults, a copying algorithm is used for minor collections, and a mark-sweep algorithm for major collections.

A copying algorithm consists of copying used memory from one block to another, and then clearing the space containing the blocks with no references to them. The copying algorithm in the JVM uses uses a large area for objects that are created for the first time (called `Eden`), and two smaller ones (called `survivors`). Surviving objects are copied once from `Eden` and several times from the `survivor` spaces during each minor collection until they become tenured and are copied to another space (called `tenured` space) where they can only be removed in a major collection.

Most of the objects in `Eden` die quickly, so the first collection copies the surviving objects to the survivor spaces (which are by default much smaller). There are two survivors `s1` and `s2`. Every time the `Eden` fills, the surviving objects from `Eden` and `s1` are copied to `s2`, `Eden` and `s1` are cleared. Next time, survivors from `Eden` and `s2` are copied back to `s1`. They keep on being copied from `s1` to `s2` to `s1` until a certain number of copies is reached, or because a block is too big and doesn't fit, or some other criteria. Then the surviving memory block is copied to the `tenured` generation.

The `tenured` objects are not affected by the minor collections. They accumulate until the area gets full (or the garbage collector is called). Then the JVM will run a mark-sweep algorithm in a major collection which will preserve only the surviving objects that still have references.

If you have larger objects that don't fit into the survivors, they might be copied directly to the `tenured` space, which will fill more quickly and you will get major collections more frequently.

Also, the sizes of the survivor spaces, amount of copies between `s1` and `s2`, `Eden` size related to the size of `s1` and `s2`, size of the tenured generation, all these may be automatically configured differently in different environments with *JVM ergonomics*, which may automatically select a `-server` or `-client` behavior. You might try to run both JVMs as `-server` or `-client` and check if they still behave differently.

Comment: Nice general explanation of the major/minor GC algorithms, but that wasn't my question.

Answer (score 1):

Even if this will get down votes... My best guess (you will have to test this) would be that the heap needs to expand and when this happens a full gc will be triggered. Not all memory is allocated at once to JVM.

You can test this by setting -Xms and -Xmx to the same value, for example 7GB each

Comment: FWIW, the OP has since commented saying that they are indeed doing this. In one environment, he/she is setting `-Xms14g -Xmx14g` and in the other, `-Xms7g -Xmx7g`.