# Dealing with 150GB heap in non interactive application

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm, java-9

Hello I am having a case of 150GB heap memory program using In Memory Data grid. I have some crazy requirement from the operational department to use a single machine. Now we all know what happens in if the parallel garbage collector is used over 150GB probably it will be tens of minutes of garbage collection if the FULL GC is invoked.

My hope was that with Java 9 is coming Shenandoah low pause GC. Unfortunately from what I see it is not listed for delivery in Java 9. Does anyone knows anything about that ?

Never the less, I am wondering how G1 GC will perform for this amount of Heap memory.

And one last question. Since I have non interactive batch application that is supposed to complete in 2 hours lets say. The main goal here is to ensure that the Full GC never kicks in. If I ensure that there is plenty of memory lets say if the maximum heap that can be reached is 150 and I allocate it 250GB may I say with good confidence that the Full GC will never kick in or ? Usually full GC is triggered if the new generation + the old generation touches the maximum heap. Can it be triggered in a different way ?

There is a duplicate request made I will try to explain here why this question is not a duplicate. First we are talking about 150GB Heap which adds completely different dimension to the question. Second I dont use RMI as it is in the question mentioned, third I am asking question about G1 garbage collector in between the lines.Also once we go beyond the 32GB heap barrier we are entering the 64 bit address space you can not convince me that a question in regards of <32GB Heap is the same as a question with heap >32GB Not to mentioned that things have changed a bit since Java 7 for instance PermSpace does not exist.

Comment: Well it is a technology question about upcoming features, is there something in stack overflow rules I am not aware of  ?

Comment: We the main motivation for this question is because I am having an application that needs 100GB+ HEAP and I am seeking options in regards of the potential garbage collection problems.

Comment: Ok I hope that with the lates Edits I have made it pass the SO policies. Please let me know if you think it can be improved.

Comment: Please check out [this meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293815/is-it-subjective-to-ask-about-why-something-wasnt-implemented-in-the-language). In my view it suggests that questions that ask one to speculate if/why a feature is in or isn't in a language is off topic. Thoughts?

Comment: I think that the key note of @Eric Lippert is if the question is answerable or not. If it is not and provokes a mere speculation than it is not a good question. I will edit the question one more time and emphasize on the large heap requirement and bearable GC pauses.

Comment: Regardless, good luck with your GC issues. Since I'm sure to know less then you on this subject, I'll have to wait with you to see if anyone provides a decent solution.

Comment: If it's non-interactive, why does it need low pause times? Parallel GC should provide the best throughput for batch tasks since it does not suffer the inefficiencies of concurrent collectors.

Comment: Because, parallel can block for tens of minutes with Heap of this size.

Comment: Yes, and? You explicitly say that the application is *non-interactive*. That implies that responsiveness - and thus pause times - should not really matter. Also, pause times depend on memory bandwidth and core count, with a sufficiently beefy machine it shouldn't be "tens of minutes", just "minutes".

Comment: Are you talking from experience or from theory ? On my laptop Parallel GC of 32 GB takes more  then 10 minutes.  What I will have as a server is 32 CPUs and up to 200GB Ram allocated.  It is correct I said no interactive, but still I have a strict license agreements. I need to be finished with the whole processing in an hour. So I can no afford 30 minutes stop the world event.

Comment: BTW why do you use IMDG? The whole purpose of IMDGs is performing computations in memory, where the total data size exceeds capacity of one machine. So IMDGs allow to cluster machines and work with their memory as it's the momory of a single machine. If you use a single machine it should be enough to use vanilla Java data structures like Maps or Lists, without heavy-weight IMDG which brings a lot of overhead I think.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am using :) And yes I know what the purpose is. Still my operations department insist I have to use one machine. And no vanilla java is not an option because I am using some rich APIs from the grid like Map Reduce and also the serialization that comes with the Maps. Serialized form is much more efficient then non serialized. Also in approximately 2 years a single machine will not be an option because of the Data growth and then we need to have the ability to scale.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes the JVM to do a major garbage collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249869/what-causes-the-jvm-to-do-a-major-garbage-collection)

Comment: Your first question "Does anyone knows anything?" is definitely not for SO. Your second question seems to be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249869/what-causes-the-jvm-to-do-a-major-garbage-collection

Comment: Have you considered storing the bulk of your data off heap?  You can have TB of data in native memory and have little impact on GC pause times.

Comment: Isn't this a payed feature:) unless it can be implemented easily without praying license fee. But yeah i guess that is an option.

Comment: @Lawrey when i say paid feature i mean the imdg provider we are using.

Comment: I like this premise that starts with “*Now we all know what happens in if the parallel garbage collector is used over 150GB*”. How many readers will actually have experience with a heap over 150GB? Everyone else doesn’t know but might just have heard something. We have an application running with ~70G never experiencing GC pauses reaching anywhere near a minute. Extrapolating from that, I see no reason why it should become “tens of minutes” with a doubled heap size…

Comment: Well it is obvious that this question is not targeting this user base. In regards of your question if a Full CG can run for minutes. I believe there is a statistic on the Terra-cotta web site showing some run times depending on the size of the heap http://terracotta.org/products/bigmemory/how-it-helps I understand that you might have been doing some tuning. But garbage collection can be a problem. I personally managed to get my 16GB PC enter in a cycle of 10 minutes GC by allocating it another 15GB virtual memory and running over 25GB heap.S test servers practically run only upon Virtual.

Comment: Their chart still does not add up to "tens of minutes".

Comment: The graph shows that the increase in time is maybe not exponential but parabolic (square). Which means that if we project the curve at 150 the time may go to up to 600 seconds which is 10 minutes. Now it is unclear on what hardware this tests are executed, but it is clear that CPU speed and physical memory frequency are crucial for the speed.  If you work in a non optimized test environment and some amount of your memory is Virtual, I can assure you it will grow to "tens" easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule of thumb for a compacting GC is that it should be able to process 1 GB of *live objects* per core per second.

Example on an Haswell i7 (4 cores/8 threads) and 20GB heap with the parallel collector:

```
[24.757s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(109) PSYoungGen: 129280K->0K(917504K)
[24.757s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(109) ParOldGen: 19471666K->7812244K(19922944K)
[24.757s][info][gc             ] GC(109) Pause Full (Ergonomics) 19141M->7629M(20352M) (23.791s, 24.757s) 966.174ms
[24.757s][info][gc,cpu         ] GC(109) User=6.41s Sys=0.02s Real=0.97s
```

The live set after compacting is 7.6GB. It takes 6.4 seconds worth of cpu-time, due to parallelism this translates to <1s pause time.

In principle the parallel collector should be able to handle a 150GB heap with full GC times < ~2 minutes on a multi-core system, even when most of the heap consists of live objects.

Of course this is just a rule of thumb. Some things that can affect it negatively:

- paging
- thermal CPU throttling
- workloads consisting of very large, reference-heavy objects
- non-local memory traffic in NUMA configurations
- other processes competing for CPU time
- heavy use of weak/soft references

In some cases tuning may be necessary to achieve this throughput.

If the Parallel collector does not work despite all that then CMS and G1 can be viable alternatives but only if there is enough spare heap capacity and CPU cores available to the JVM. They need significant breathing room to do their concurrent work without risking a full GC.

> It is correct I said no interactive, but still I have a strict license agreements. I need to be finished with the whole processing in an hour. So I can no afford 30 minutes stop the world event.

Basically, you don't really need low pause times in the sense that CMS, G1, Shenandoah or Zing aim for (they aim for <100ms or even <10ms even on large heaps).

All you need is that STW pauses are not so catastrophically bad that they eat a significant portion of your compute time.

This should be feasible with most of the available collectors, ignoring the serial one.

In practice there are some pathological edge cases where they may fall down, but to get to that point you need setup a system with your actual workload and do some test runs. If you experience some real problems, then you can ask a question with more details.

Comment: Thanks i need some time to think over your post. Will come back.

Comment: Hi can you say a little about the heavy use of weak/soft references. Why this would reduce the speed. Is it because of the memory fragmentation or ?

Comment: Also on local PC the G1 collector gave me better execution times compared to the Parallel collector. I was expecting the opposite. I have run my tests over several minutes so It is not a test setup thing.

Comment: Reference processing extends lifetimes and means extra work for the GC. Also it's single-threaded by default. And for the execution times: parallel collector processes the whole live data set for old gen collections, G1 does not (but collects more often), this may have an impact. And there may be some edge-cases where specific phases of one GC are single-threaded while the other is better parallelized, to some extent this depends on tuning too. Without further information it's all guesswork. It's usually better to measure with detailed GC logs to get the facts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Accepted.